# Switch Metamask Network to chain 1 (Ethereum Mainnet)

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

This past week Metamask introduced a new function called "wallet_addEthereumChain" which allows the user to automatically add a new Etheruem RPC to their wallet when prompted.  This function also allows the user to change the network they are connected to, for example, if I already have Binance Smart Chain connected to metamask, calling wallet_addEthereumChain changes the active network to BSC.  However, when trying this for the Ethereum chain, it gives an error that you cannot add mainnet RPC.

I have used the following code to change to change from Ethereum Mainnet to Binance Smart Chain, and it works fine:

```
    switchToBinance: async function () {

        let ethereum = window.ethereum;
        const data = [{
            chainId: '0x38',
            chainName: 'Binance Smart Chain',
            nativeCurrency:
                {
                    name: 'BNB',
                    symbol: 'BNB',
                    decimals: 18
                },
            rpcUrls: ['https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'],
            blockExplorerUrls: ['https://bscscan.com/'],
        }]
        /* eslint-disable */
        const tx = await ethereum.request({method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain', params:data}).catch()
        if (tx) {
            console.log(tx)
        }
    },
```

However when I try the Exact thing, metamask throws an exception saying I cannot add a mainnet RPC:
switchToEthereum: async function () {

```
        let ethereum = window.ethereum;
        const data = [{
      chainId: '0x1',
      chainName: 'Ethereum',
      nativeCurrency: {
        name: 'Ethereum',
        symbol: 'ETH',
        decimals: 18,
      },
      rpcUrls: ['https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/undefined'],
      blockExplorerUrls: ['https://etherscan.io'],
    }]
        /* eslint-disable */
        const tx = await ethereum.request({method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain', params:data}).catch()
        if (tx) {
            console.log(tx)
        }
    },
```

However, the request for adding a new RPC connection, and changing the active RPC connection is the same.    So is there a way to change the active Ethereum provider from a custom chain to Mainnet (chain ID-1)

Comment: I've encountered the same behavior and error, with mainnet and the 4 testnets. It's something in the way MetaMask is implementing the RPC call. I suggest opening an issue on MetaMask's Github (and post a link to it here for posterity).

Answer (score 6):

Simply you have to prefix **0x** with the chainId.

**Example:**

```
 await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
    params: [{ chainId: '0x1' }],
 })
```

Answer (score 5):

as this [issue comment](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/10597#issuecomment-791525135) point, for security reason `wallet_addEthereumChain` not support mainnet. But there a new EIP to resolve this issue, follow [EIP-3326](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/3326) to find release info, and this [discuss](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/eip-3326-wallet-switchethereumchain/5471) to see draft progrss.

Answer (score 3):

```
chainId: '0x38' // error because await not decimal 

Number('0x38').toString(10) //56 - chain ID of BSC
```

Right:

```
chainId: `0x${Number(56).toString(16)}`
```

OR:

```
chainId: `0x86`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).